# Is there a way to prevent software from accessing hardware IDs?

Tags: operating-systems, hardware, anonymity, identity, spyware

I think this is related to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33697/what-devices-types-of-devices-typically-have-unique-associated-id-numbers), but I would like to know if there's also a way to prevent "third party" applications from seeing hardware IDs (motherboard, hard disks, and others), or giving them fake values, on real OS, not using a virtual machine. I'm interested here in modern mainstream desktop OSes, (and especially interesting are Windows 7 and Windows 8 for x86-64).

Comment: can you also specify which "software" you mean? drivers are software. Shareware is software. A webbrowser is software. surely it might matter

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I mean all the software except the OS itself.

Comment: No, you cannot prevent a software from accessing hardware IDs, as this is how its designed in most operating systems. However, for changing the IDs you'll need root access to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this via [Google's Native Client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client). However, executables have to be compiled for this environment explicitely.

It is difficult to achieve otherwise (i.e. without a sandbox). DEP can't do this for you, as it only prevents memory segments without the executable flag from being executed.

Just think of reading the CPUID, which is a simple instruction which you can normally not prevent from being executed.

Anyway, there may be programs to do this which utilize debugging features, but I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

[Hardware enforced DEP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912923) may be able to prevent, unsure about returning false values

Comment: How it does this? From my understanding, it only disallows executing instructions that are stored in memory that's not marked as executable.

Comment: You're likely going to get a quicker more accurate answer asking on the Microsoft forums if you ask me... http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/home?category=w7itpro%2Cw8itpro%2Cwindowsvistaitpro%2Cwindowsxpitpro%2Cwindowsintune